# Run a parsed function in parallel in Julia

Tags: parallel-processing, julia

I want to run a function in parallel, where the function is provided via a string argument. It is parsed from string to an Expression first and then run in parallel.

The problem is that the string argument is not known to all worker processes.

How can I make this work:

```
module test

function run(f)

 @everywhere f_exp = eval(parse(f))

 values = SharedArray(Float64,2)
 @sync @parallel for i = 1:2
  values[i] = f_exp(i)
 end

 return mean(values)
end

end

# RUN AS FOLLOWS
# @everywhere include("c:\\projects\\evaluator\\test.jl")
# test.run("function func(x) return 2*x end")
```

I also tried `@everywhere f_exp = eval(parse("@everywhere $f"))`, though I did not expect it to work... and it didn't.

How can I make the argument known to every process?

Doing `@everywhere f` as the first line in the function run also did not do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work if I do not have a `module...end` around the code as follows:

```
function run(f)

 @eval @everywhere f = $f
 @everywhere f_exp = eval(parse(f))

 values = SharedArray(Float64,2)
 @sync @parallel for i = 1:2
  values[i] = f_exp(i)
 end

 return mean(values)
end
```

If I surround this function with `module...end`, I get an error similar to: ##9#11 not defined (on worker 2)

I have an idea that the reason that it does not work with `module...end` is the `@everywhere` uses module Main ... I tried something in this direction but did not get it to work